# Facebook Feed dialogs Problem

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

when I use the feed dialog code from the developer's pages, the feed dialog works ( I am testing locally ).

but if I substitute my app_id/my_canvas_url I get an error.

any thoughts please...

thanks for your time,
Shannon

Comment: Can you post sample code for the post you are trying to generate?  I am unsure if i understand what you mean by substitute app_id, as per canvas_url - the feed dialog is meant to share external links not Facebook links.

Comment: Shawn, thanks for your response ... 

I would love to post the code, but this StackOverflow will not allow me to do so ... I must wait 8 hours before I can do anything ...

Comment: however, if you visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ 

you can see their example Feed code ... if I simply replace their app_id and their link with MY info, it generates an error.

I am testing on my local machine.

- Shannon

Comment: What error are you receiving? It's difficult to help without knowing what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the domain of the redirect_uri to the Facebook App. Goto Developers >> Apps >> Edit App >> and then add keleia.com into the app domains

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

seems like it is related to domain...  my app ( ie canvas url ) is located on keleia.com.

WORKS: 
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed/?app_id=208524139202627&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com

DOESN'T: 
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed/?app_id=208524139202627&redirect_uri=http://www.keleia.com